# IOUtils.toByteArray is returning empty byte array

Tags: java, sql, arrays, binarystream, ioutils

I am new to Java development so apologies in advance if I am asking something stupid.

I am trying to retrieve an image and it's thumbnail from sql database. 
I get data from `ResultSet` in `BinaryStream` format and then convert it to `byte[]`.

For thumbnail it works fine and for original image too I am able to retrieve `BinaryStream` using `getBinaryStream` method **But** when I convert it to `byte[]`, **the array remain empty for some reason**.

```
binaryStream = rs.getBinaryStream("image");
thumbBinaryStream = rs.getBinaryStream("thumbnail");
if (binaryStream != null) {
    // Tested on following line and I get empty imageBytes
    byte[] imageBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(binaryStream); 
    thisRecord.put("image", DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageBytes)); // imageBytes is empty here 
}
```

Comment: Why bother with an InputStream at all?  Why not call [ResultSet.getBytes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBytes(java.lang.String))?  As in, `byte[] imageBytes = rs.getBytes("image");`?

Comment: I have tried both ways but `imageBytes` remains empty while if I do the same with `thumbBinaryStream` and convert it to bytes, I get the data.

Answer (score 0):

We probably need more information, especially about the datatypes of the columns, but maybe it helps to retrieve the stream from the BLOB like in this example:

```
if (rs.getMetaData().getColumnType(column) == Types.BLOB) {
        in = rs.getBlob(column).getBinaryStream();
    } else {
        in = rs.getBinaryStream(column);
    }
```

Comment: thumbnail and image both are LONGBLOB and are of exactly same type. But the problem is it works for one and not for other.

Comment: It is recommended to retrieve the stream from the result of getBlob(columnName) for large binary data, so you should give it a try. Otherwise check if there is data at all 

Comment: I have checked by simply by running query and BLOB is there. I have tried with BLOB but no change. I am surprised that why I am getting data from thumbnail column using same code.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure:
Statement and ResultSet must be closed and `getBinaryStream` only used when the ResultSet is still open, like:

```
try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        InputStream binaryStream = rs.getBinaryStream("image");
        InputStream thumbBinaryStream = rs.getBinaryStream("thumbnail");
        if (binaryStream != null) {
            // Tested on following line and I get empty imageBytes
            byte[] imageBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(binaryStream); 
            thisRecord.put("image", DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageBytes));
            boolean mustGenerateThumbnail = thumbBinaryStream == null;
            if (mustGenerateThumbnail ) {
                thumbBinaryStream = generateThumbnail(imageBytes);
            }
            byte[] thumbBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(thumbBinaryStream);
            thisRecord.put("thumbnail", DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(thumbBytes));
```

Here we are at the error. At this point thumbBinaryStream is read till the end, so do:

```
            if (mustGenerateThumbnail ) {
                ByteArrayInputStream baIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(thumbBytes);
                saveThumbnailForRecordWithId(baIn, floor_drawing_id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Here I used try-with-resources to automatically close the ResultSet even on thrown exception.)

Furthermore there is a more general class for Base64. Should you in future have the need for such.

```
DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(thumbBytes)
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(thumbBytes)
```

Comment: I have updated my code so that you understand my problem more clearly. I am sorry, I added unrelated code before.

Comment: And the ResultSet rs is still open it seems. It could be that no thumb gives just an empty (non-null) InputStream resulting in zero bytes.

Comment: I get data when I try to get thumbnail but I get empty byte array when I try to get image. so `byte[] thumbBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(thumbBinaryStream);` this works fine while `byte[] imageBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(binaryStream);` this does not. I am sure that data is in there in db. I have inserted data in same way in both fields.

Comment: I start to mistrust `generateThumbnail` as the rest of the code is plausible. Sorry to be of no help here.